# How to apply And where condition in orWhere?

Tags: laravel

I want to display data from cv table where user_id is $request->id.
Also, filtering is done so i have to put lots of orWhere.
Because of this my code is not working as expected.
Sorry question is a little bit confusing.

```
 $search = $request->input('search.value');
 $results = cv::with(['industrySegments','jobLocations','jobPositions','languages'])->where('user_id',$request->id);
 $results->orWhere('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
 $results->orWhere('gender','LIKE',$search);
 $results->orWhere('contact','LIKE',$search);
 $results->orWhere('contact2','LIKE',$search);
```

This code doesn't work.
whenever i type something in search button it displays data that is not supposed to be display.
I want to display only the data whose user_id is $request->id.

Answer (score 0):

Test next code:

```
$results = cv::with(['industrySegments','jobLocations','jobPositions','languages']);

if(!empty($request->id))
{
 $results->where('user_id',$request->id);
}
else
{
 $results->orWhere('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
 $results->orWhere('gender','LIKE',$search);
 $results->orWhere('contact','LIKE',$search);
 $results->orWhere('contact2','LIKE',$search);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you wanted to do is [advanced where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

your query will be like this

```
$results = cv::with(['industrySegments','jobLocations','jobPositions','languages'])->where('user_id',$request->id)->where(function($q)use($search){
    $q->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%")->orWhere(..........;    
})->get();
```

therefore you can play around with where / orWhere

Comment: now it shows only user_id data but search doesn't work. I mean orWhere not working because it is not filtering

Comment: @A4family try change all orWhere to where inside the advanced where? you can play around with it